# Bob starts with \$20. Bob flips a coin. Heads = Win +\$1 Tails = Lose -\$1. Stops if he has \$0 or \$100. Probability he ends up with \$0?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm working on the extra credit for my Discrete Structures homework, but so far I have been unable to get a handle on the problem, even with help from 3rd parties, so I've decided to turn to you guys. The title explains the essentials, but I've included the full wording below, along with some notes.

Extra Credit Problem: Consider a game of gambling, where Bob started with 20 dollars in his pocket. Each time Bob wins, he will earn 1 dollar and each time he loses he will lose 1 dollar. A fair coin is flipped to decide win or loss, head = win & tails = loss. Bob will stop playing if his balance reaches 100 dollars or 0 dollars. What is the probability that Bob is ruined? (He loses all his money, as opposed to returning home with $100 in his pocket.)

The question is as such:

Let $P_k$ be the probability that Bob is ruined when he has k dollars in his pocket.

a. Write a recurrence relation for $P_k$

b. Solve the recurrence relation to find the answer.

Note that $P_0 = 100\%$ (with no money Bob is ruined) and $P_{100} = 0\%$ (Because Bob returns with 100 dollars in his pocket and the game is over for Bob, so he is not ruined.)

Basically, I'm at a loss for how to create this recurrence relation. I started by investigating what information I might be able to derive from the given values of P, but honestly I'm not sure if this is really helpful. Solving the relations does not seem to be as difficult, but creating them has proved extremely challenging for me, if anyone has advice on a good way to think about this or some sort of methodology that helps you personally it would be well received.

Any help you could provide is much appreciated, I'd really like to get this extra credit or at least be able to understand how it works, because the professor generally doesn't go over the HW unless explicitly asked about a problem and even then it's very quickly, so that we have time in lecture to cover the new/current material. Also, the next time we have lecture will be the same day the HW is due, which limits the time I'll be able to spend with any hints given.

Comment: @user23442: Where are you stuck? What type of help do you need/want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If he has $k$ dollars, there is a $50\%$ chance he loses a dollar and a $50\%$  chance he gains a dollar. Then the probabilities for those amounts determine how likely he will be ruined. The relation is
$$P_k=\frac12P_{k-1}+\frac12P_{k+1}$$
Which when combined with the initial conditions is
$$P_{k+1}=2P_k-P_{k-1}; \,P_0=1, P_{100}=0$$
From here you can solve the recurrence relation to get
$$P_k=1-\frac k {100}$$

Comment: Thank you for the help Pauly, I managed to fill in the steps you left out on my own and it was extremely satisfying being able to check my answer.

Answer (score 3):

For general problems of this kind I would recommend using a method based on deriving the recurrence relation (see e.g. the post by Pauly B).

However in this particular case, where the probabilities of winning or losing a coin toss are exactly $50$% , there is a much simpler approach possible. Let us assume that we play this entire game many more times. Sometimes we win $80$ dollars, sometimes we lose $20$. Since the game is fair, we can immediately conclude that the probability of losing must be a factor $4$ larger. It follows that the probability of losing is $80$ %.

Answer (score 1):

Say he has $k$ dollars. Next round he is going to have either $k-1$ or $k+1$ dollars. Use the probabilities of these things happening together with $P_{k+1}$ and $P_{k-1}$ to create the recurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Lets see : how can Bob be ruined with k dollars? What if his name is not Bob??? :) . Hope this will give you enough to do it yourself.

Let's see the scenarios:

For k=1, a single string $T$ will ruin him on the first trial , a string $HTT$ will ruin him on three trials. For 5 trials, we can have $HTHTT, HHTTT$, all starting with $H$ , notice we always have one more tail than heads in each ruin. Can you show that for $k$ dollars, there will be $k$ more heads than tails?

Comment: How does this help in finding a recurrence relation?

Comment: How does yours? Is it any more explicit? I am giving a layout. OP says s/he wants to know how it works, so I will answer any follow ups. Ultimately, lets let the OP decide which is helpful to him/her.

Comment: Just curious, did you edit the comment above or delete and repost it? I'm trying to figure out if I got pinged because a comment was edited.

Comment: I deleted and rewrote because the system was preventing me from editing . Sorry for the additional pingback.

Comment: Damn. My hopes are shattered :) thanks

Comment: Sorry, I am just not clear at what point the OP is stuck. Is s/he unable to come up with a layout, etc? So I am suggesting a basic layout and then will adapt my post to any folowup, or maybe delete if it does not seem helpful. That is what I am aiming for.

Comment: It is my understanding that the goal is to find an equation expressing $P_k$ in terms of other ruin probabilities.

Comment: But where is the OP stuck in this respect? I am assuming in the basic layout. I will rewrite if OP asks a followup, or delete if some other answer is accepted. I am just not clear on what type of help the OP is looking fo in order to do the recursion.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask for clarification from the OP then. Someone posted an explicit answer but the OP did express desire to know the reasoning behind coming up with these things.

Comment: Just asked the OP for clarification. I just thought I would set up some basic ideas for the sake of creating a context for OP to ask followups. We'll see ( if the Op does follow up).

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for the help. Gary I did see your post first and have been trying to work on the problem for the past couple hours. I was unable to come up with the recurrence relation on my own just with this, but did use @matt_samuel's hint in conjunction with your own to successfully gain greater insight into how you might formulate the relation organically. Honestly, very helpful and much appreciated.

If you're still curious Gary, I was simply at a loss for how to think about the relation. The k+1 vs k-1 was the key for getting the solution to click if you will.

Comment: @user234442: Glad t helped.

Comment: mm another anonymous downvote. Happy Holidays in the dark, wherever you are.

Answer (score 0):

At each coin throw his expected win is zero. He will go home having lost \$20 with some probability p, and having won \$80 with probability 1-p. His expected total winnings is 0, so -20p + 80(1-p) = 0, or 80 = 100p or p = 0.8.

There is no need to calculate any of the probabilities in between.